# Trouble understanding how this rate limiter works

Tags: go

I've been trying to make a rate limiter for my application and came across this code. After reading it I still have some trouble understanding what it does exactly.

My current understanding:

1) SetSmallRateLimit and SetLongRateLimit are called to initialize the channels and starts running the handlers in a goroutine.

2) When requestAndUnmarshal is called, checkRateLimiter sends a signal to the queue channel.

What I don't understand:

1) RateLimitHandler sleeps the duration of time.After(pertime) and afterwards clears the queue channel. Not sure what triggerWatcher and returnChan are doing.

2) checkTimeTrigger - Don't understand what this function is doing or its purpose.

```
var (
    smallRateChan   rateChan
    longRateChan    rateChan
)

type rateChan struct {
    RateQueue   chan bool
    TriggerChan chan bool
}

//10 requests every 10 seconds
func SetSmallRateLimit(numrequests int, pertime time.Duration) {
    smallRateChan = rateChan{
        RateQueue:   make(chan bool, numrequests),
        TriggerChan: make(chan bool),
    }
    go rateLimitHandler(smallRateChan, pertime)
}

//500 requests every 10 minutes
func SetLongRateLimit(numrequests int, pertime time.Duration) {
    longRateChan = rateChan{
        RateQueue:   make(chan bool, numrequests),
        TriggerChan: make(chan bool),
    }
    go rateLimitHandler(longRateChan, pertime)
}

func rateLimitHandler(RateChan rateChan, pertime time.Duration) {
    returnChan := make(chan bool)
    go timeTriggerWatcher(RateChan.TriggerChan, returnChan)
    for {
        <-returnChan
        <-time.After(pertime)
        go timeTriggerWatcher(RateChan.TriggerChan, returnChan)
        length := len(RateChan.RateQueue)
        for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
            <-RateChan.RateQueue
        }
    }
}

func timeTriggerWatcher(timeTrigger chan bool, returnChan chan bool) {
    timeTrigger <- true
    returnChan <- true
}

func requestAndUnmarshal(requestURL string, v interface{}) (err error) {
    checkRateLimiter(smallRateChan)
    checkRateLimiter(longRateChan)
    resp, err := http.Get(requestURL)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    checkTimeTrigger(smallRateChan)
    checkTimeTrigger(longRateChan)
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return RiotError{StatusCode: resp.StatusCode}
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(body, v)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    return
}

func checkRateLimiter(RateChan rateChan) {
    if RateChan.RateQueue != nil && RateChan.TriggerChan != nil {
        RateChan.RateQueue <- true
    }
}

func checkTimeTrigger(RateChan rateChan) {
    if RateChan.RateQueue != nil && RateChan.TriggerChan != nil {
        select {
        case <-RateChan.TriggerChan:
        default:
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should use this code to learn anything useful. **I'm not sure** but it seems to try to limit the request rate but it's wrong. It allows to make certain amount of request and then wait for a time interval. After the time interval it allows you to make requests again. All of that is done in a very sophisticated way.

But it can lead to very strange scenarios. Let's say you make 1req/h and your limit is 500req/20sec. Then this code would cause you to wait 20sec after 500 hours and allow to make requests again.

`checkTimeTrigger` removes a message from RateChan.TriggerChan if it has any and does nothing if it has not and returns immediately.

This code isn't obviously [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). Better use https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/time/rate is you want to limit your request rate.

Comment: Having a "burst" rate and a "longer-term, steady-state" rate is frequently useful. Not necessarily with the ratios you provided (90 000 requests/s as a burst rate, 0.00028 requests / s for steady state). If your values are more sensible (steady-state 1 request / s, burst rate 5 requests / s; say), this is a useful method for rate-limiting.